# Failed to load resource even though it is there

Tags: javascript, magento, nginx, permissions, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a failed to load resource error in my browser console.

```
http://our-magento-site.com/skin/frontend/blacknwhite/default/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is only happening on our staging environment, not on my local machine.

When I try to open http://our-magento-site.com/skin/frontend/blacknwhite/default/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js in a browser I'm getting the same 404 error.

I checked and the file exists on our server and I can open it in VIM.  The permissions also seem correct and the same as other resources which are loading fine on the page.

```
ls -al skin/frontend/blacknwhite/default/js/
total 296
dr-x------ 3 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 27 10:03 .
dr-x------ 6 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 27 10:03 ..
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  3174 Jul 27 10:03 ajaxwishlist.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  5935 Jul 27 10:03 cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js
dr-x------ 2 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 27 10:03 configurableswatches
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 16016 Jul 27 10:03 css3-mediaqueries.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  2394 Jul 27 10:03 html5.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  4233 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.backstretch.min.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  3095 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.cookie.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  8096 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.easing.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 22595 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.fancybox.pack.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 32893 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.iosslider.min.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 37336 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.iosslider.min_rtl.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 15954 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.isotope.min.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 16243 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.isotope.min_rtl.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  1552 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  2235 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.mousewheel.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  1785 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  8112 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  1762 Jul 27 10:03 jquery.ui.totop.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  6254 Jul 27 10:03 script_ie.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data 61109 Jul 27 10:03 script.js
-r-------- 1 www-data www-data  4836 Jul 27 10:03 selectivizr-min.js
```

Not really sure what could be happening here?

We're running Magento 1.9.2 on an NGINX HHVM server ubuntu 14.04 on an AWS instance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so while troubleshooting the problem it somehow became solved.  I don't quite understand how & why but it now works.

This is what I did, I create a bunch of copies of the file to see if I could access them in the browser.

```
jquery.parallax-1.1.4.js  # 404 error
jquery.parallax-1.1.js # 404 error
jquery.parallax-1-1-3.js # could access, success
jquery.parallax-1.js # could access, success
jquery.parallax.js # could access, success
```

Then I checked again and I was now able to access jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js, for some unknown reason the problem went away after creating copies and accessing them in the browser.  Maybe it was a Magento URL re-writing issue?  I don't know.

When I removed each of these newly copied files the problem re-occurred.  then when I created a copy of the file called `jquery.parallax-1.js` the problem went away again.

Answer (score 1):

Set file permission to 644, It should be load after that.

Comment: That wasn't it, also the file permissions I have are the ones [recommended by Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).  I got it working in the end, but am not really sure how, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. I noticed that it's how the file is named. For me `/static/version1545416633/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js` is the issue.

if you remove the `version1545416633` part from the url and create a copy of the file named `jquery-ui-1.9.js` it will work in a browser as the original filename, but if you keep the `version1545416633` in the url then the file needs to be named `jquery-ui-1.js`... I assume some kind of htaccess issue.

This issue just decided to start happening after a recent Magento setup:upgrade and di:compile. It makes no sense to me.

I will update this answer if i find the cause.